# Conditionally project a field value in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, conditional-statements, project, aggregation

**I have a mongo document as below.
**

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "docId": "7b96a"
  },
  "items": {
    "content": "abcd",
    "contentWithInfo": "content with additional info"
  }
}
```

I want to project content field based on the condition whether contentWithInfo field is present or not. If contentWithInfo is present, it's value should be projected as content field value and contentWithInfo should be empty. Otherwise content should be projected as is. Is it possible?

**I tried the following shell query:**

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "metadata.docId": {
        "$in": [
          "7b96a"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$items"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "metadata": 1,
      "items.content": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$eq": [
              "$items.contentWithInfo",
              null
            ]
          },
          "then": "$items.content",
          "else": "$items.contentWithInfo"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

If contentWithInfo is present, it is returning the following:

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "docId": "7b96a"
  },
  "items": {
    "content": "content with additional info"
  }
}
```

If contentWithInfo is not present, it is returning the following:

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "docId": "7b96a"
  },
  "items": {}
}
```

whereas I expect it to return

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "docId": "7b96a"
  },
  "items": {
    "content": "abcd"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach 1**

Instead of checking `items.contentWithInfo` is null, check whether the `items.contentWithInfo` is missing with `$type` operator.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "metadata.docId": {
        "$in": [
          "7b96a"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$items"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "metadata": 1,
      "items.content": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$eq": [
              {
                $type: "$items.contentWithInfo"
              },
              "missing"
            ]
          },
          "then": "$items.content",
          "else": "$items.contentWithInfo"
        }        
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo Approach 1 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/h9XrReR2jV0)

Another approach, if you want `items.content` as default value if `items.contentWithInfo` is missing or null, you can use `$ifNull` operator.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "metadata.docId": {
        "$in": [
          "7b96a"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$items"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "metadata": 1,
      "items.content": {
        $ifNull: [
          "$items.contentWithInfo",
          "$items.content"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo Approach 2 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tbhmVwakf7k)